# how to get a single value from the below json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How to get a single value from the below JSON data.

```html
['A',
 'B',
 'C',
 'D'
]
```

Output:
1:A
2:B
3:C
4:D

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```js
const arr = ['A',
 'B',
 'C',
 'D'
];
const obj = Object.fromEntries(arr.map((e,i)=>[i+1,e]));
// {1: "A", 2: "B", 3: "C", 4: "D"}
```

Then you could access the values by the key
for instance :

```js
obj[1]; //A
obj[2]; //B
//...
```